# Replacing dots and whitespace

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I am using this code to replace dots and whitespaces. My problem is that The whitespace removal is not working in all cases. If for example i have string "hello " it should replace the whitespace at the end of hello but doesn't. This string is imported from another worksheet. I delete whatever that space is at the end of hello and manually replace with a whitespace, then the vba code works to replace that whitespace. It is almost like whatever that trailing character is, it is not a whitespace. Then with dots so for example "hello......" it will remove only two dots so I get "hello....". Anyone have any suggestions why I am facing this issue?

Comment: There are many characters that look like others. You will need to find what those characters are and add replacement lines for them also.

Comment: You are removing standard spaces. Try adding a `What:=Chr(160)` to remove non-breaking spaces.

Comment: In the worksheet use `=unicode(right(a1))` to get the ascii or unicode dec number of the trailing 'space' character.

Comment: Excellent, the Chr(160) replacement solved my problem on the trailing space issue. The dots is still unresolved but not an issue for what i'm trying to do, just an observation when i was playing around, even with straightforward excel replace from toolbar it won.t remove all dots,

Comment: Most likely due to the same issue.  There is more than one character that looks like a dot.

Comment: Must be but it seems strange. If I type ...... in any cell and then use the excel Replace from toolbar to replace dots on that cell it won't remove them all

Answer (score 0):

To removing the whitespace, I suggest to use the TRIM function of VBA and code as following:

```
Sub DeWhitespace()
Dim a As Long
a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Range("Q2", "Q" & a).FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
End Sub
```